# Convert SQL query/subquery to LINQ (VB)

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I'm stuck, someone give me a push please.

Here is my SQL query..

```
SELECT EqID, MakeID, Model, Description,
   (SELECT MAX(EvDateEnd) AS MaxOfDateEnd
     FROM tblEvent WHERE (EqID = tblEquip.EqID) AND (Event = 'REG')) AS RegExpire,
   (SELECT Entity FROM tblEvent AS tblEvent_3 WHERE (EqID = tblEquip.EqID) AND(Event = N'EAE') AND (EvDateEnd IS NULL)) AS IssuedTo
FROM tblEquip
```

Why I'm doing it this way, If there is a better way, I'm all ears.

tblEquip lists rows of Equipment, EqID is the PK
tblEvent lists many Events that relate to the equipment, EqID is the FK

For example, I want to get the Max EvDateEnd from the Events table for each record in tblEquip, but not all records in tblEquip have the "REG" event, while others have multiple REG events.

Some events (like EAE) I leave the tblEvent.EvDateEnd field blank to show the event is open and ongoing, such as issuing a vehicle to an employee(entity). when the vehicle is returned I enter the date in EvDateEnd essentially closing the event.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/), I get this output.  Because you are joining to `tblEquip` in two separate ways, and I'm assuming the 2nd method will be guaranteed to return 0 or 1 row, then this format is about as good as you'll get.

```
from tblequip in db.TblEquip
select new {
  tblequip.EqID,
  tblequip.MakeID,
  tblequip.Model,
  tblequip.Description,
  RegExpire = 
    (from tblevent in db.TblEvent
    where
      tblevent.EqID == tblequip.EqID &&
      tblevent.Event == "REG"
    select new {
      tblevent.EvDateEnd
    }).Max(p => p.EvDateEnd),
  IssuedTo = (System.Int32?)
    ((from tblevent_3 in db.TblEvent
    where
      tblevent_3.EqID == tblequip.EqID &&
      tblevent_3.Event == "EAE" &&
      tblevent_3.EvDateEnd == null
    select new {
      tblevent_3.Entity
    }).First().Entity)
```